# For player damage but no environment damage should I choose Adventure Mode or Survival Mode?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am making a Star wars PVP Map, featuring The Empire and Rebels and some props. Players would be assigned to one of the teams and the battle would begin. Since I play Minecraft Java 1.12.2 (because all other versions are blocked) at school, there are always griefers in multiplayer. So I set the default game mode to Adventure when opening to LAN. However, I am not sure (too scared to try, my school has too many griefers) if you can damage players in Adventure Mode.

I make a "lobby" where spawn area is. I give creative to my friends and we made a "Dungeon of Shame" where we teleport any griefers or suspicious players into it. Now, when we start a PVP match in this world, I don't know if I should keep it as Adventure Mode or switch to Survival Mode. I do want players to be able to take damage, BUT I also want players to not be able to damage the environment (star destroyers, ground, buildings, etc.).

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Players in adventure mode are capable of dealing and taking damage normally. Adventure mode only prevents players from placing and destroying blocks.

Comment: Ah ok. So I should do Adventure mode then, correct?

Comment: Yes, that does follow from my answer.